# How many ways to sit people on a bench in the same order

Tags: combinatorics

So I am stuck on a combinatorics problem. I know that there might be similar questions like this but I couldn't find the right one.

Imagine we have a bench with $n$ places and we need to sit $m$ people.
We assume that there less people than places, $m < n$. And we also want our people to stay in the same order:

Ex. $n = 4$ places; $m = 2$ people

```
AB--
-AB-
--AB
A-B-
-A-B
A--B
```

What binomial coefficient formula can I use to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Choose which of the positions on the bench are left empty versus occupied by people.  Given such a selection, the people will sit in the prescribed order in the seats available to them.

> $\binom{n}{m}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The only freedom you have available to you is to choose which $m$ of the $n$ seats will be taken.